# Get TortoiseHG to remember which file filters I selected?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Every time I restart Tortoise HG it resets the set of selected file filters:

[image]

The "ignored" and "subrep" items always come back CHECKED even though my preference is to leave them off.

Most THG settings end up in `Mercurial.ini` but as far as I can tell this one isn't being saved at all. Is there anything I can do to make it so?

---

I'm using:

```
TortoiseHg 
version 5.9.2 
with Mercurial-5.9.2, Python-2.7.18, PyQt-5.13.2, Qt-5.9.9
```

but this has happened in every version I can remember.